# Service Oriented Architecture

Tags: javascript, html, xml, jsp, soa

I have an already existing code which i want to convert it to Service Oriented Architecture.
For this, i consider MYSQL database as service provider which has some services like generating reports for number of days, etc. The service consumer is any user from GUI which asks for services. I have service directory on the GUI which shows the available list of services. The user can select the required service from GUI. Now, when he clicks on the service he requires, it asks for the input like number of days. All that code is written in html, java script, jsp. It takes the inputs and passes the inputs to another page and a shell script is written to generate the required pdf. 
Can i convert the code written in html,java script, jsp to xml.
The way i'm approaching is Service Oriented Architecture or not?
I couldn't find any code on Service Oriented Architecture

Comment: XML is not a programming language. SOA is not about writing programs in XML. Your question doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Then why do we use XML in SOA. I'm new to programming and even to SOA.

Comment: XML is used to transfer data from a caller to a service, and vice-versa.

Comment: What i learnt about HTML and XML is that HTML is used to display the data and XML is used to store and transport the data. Then, Can i say my existing code as SOA, even without using XML.

Comment: Why do you care if your design is SOA or not?! and for that matter why do you want an SOA ?
What are the problems with your current design?

SOA is an architecture style which is all about flexibility and change, it is suitable as a way for adding these traits into large complex systems- what you describe is a reporting application on top of an RDBMS, from the details you provided it hardly sounds you need 3 tiers

Comment: We have already implemented a project. I just want to convert it into SOA. Not only reporting but there are some other parameters also. I consider report generation as a service. That report generation what i have mentioned surely uses Database, but we give it from the (GUI)front end by sitting anywhere on the web. I need to know whether my approach is correct or not.

Answer (score 2):

SOA is not really applicable to what you are doing. XML is not a criteria to implement SOA, either.

SOA does not have much to do with end users anyway. It's a mean to structure application design within an enterprise with multiple applications.

In a nutshell, Service Oriented Architecture is an architecture style to create well defined services with well defined interfaces for information exchange between (and sometimes inside) applications. For example, instead of applications reading directly each others database tables, a web service might be defined that fronts the database table with a defined interface. But SOA is not restricted to SOAP/WS/WSDL/BPEL or any other XML technology.

It's uncommon to decouple a GUI with the database backend using SOA services (which I think is what your are trying to achieve). It's more common to decouple different applications or domain components within an application.